how to remove container mobaxterm
mobaxterm says:
Starting Shadowbox .......................... FAILED
The container name "shadowbox" is already in use by another container. This may happen when running this script multiple times. We will attempt to remove the existing container and restart it. Would you like to proceed? [Y/n]
but when i type Y it becomes looking like that:
Removing shadowbox container ................ OK
Restarting shadowbox ........................ FAILED
The container name "shadowbox" is already in use by another container. This may happen when running this script multiple times. We will attempt to remove the existing container and restart it

I'm not sure this is answerable unless your question tells us what "shadowbox" is and where you got it from and perhaps provide a link to whatever instructions you are following. There are several possibilities, so help us to help you. A mention of your Ubuntu flavor and version would also be very helpful. mobaxterm seems irrelevant if that is just your remote-access application your client system.
